# Cannot link my CSS Bootstrap file in VS Code

Tags: css, angular, visual-studio-code, bootstrap-4

I am unable to link my bootstrap file to my HTML in VS Code, since I have linked it, it does not work.

[image]

Comment: You can use one of this getting started guides https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/getting-started

Answer (score 1):

In case this is a angular-cli project and you want to use bootstrap throughout the project the right way is to install it via npm like:

```
npm install bootstrap --save
```

and then make sure the file-references are in the angular-cli.json files under styles & scripts:

```
  "styles": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.css",
    ....
    ...
    "styles.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"
    ....
    ..
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<link href="./bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to import in your style-sheet (CSS/SCSS) like this:

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-reboot';

@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-grid';
```